# Help with KQL query search not returning any result

Tags: search, search-api, kql-query

I have installed the search query tool and i'm sure i have the properties Birthday and Department updated in my SharePoint user profile.

But using the below queries yields no result

To list everyone in this department:

```
 Department="Microsoft Consulting"  ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

To list people that have birthdays before today (The RefinableDate17 is mapped to SPS-Birthday):

```
   RefinableDate17<2023-[FORMATDATE("MM-DD")] ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople
```

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I would begin by searching for your profile and ensure that the data was populated in those fields. I find this is usually the issue. Can you craft a query that returns those fields and see the data.

Comment: THanks Matthew. I can confirm the data is populated by directly going to user profile in SharePoint Admin and its there.
My question was is my query ok

Comment: That's not what I mean. Search does not use that data, it only uses the RefinableDate field in your example. You need to be certain that those fields contain the data you are attempting to query. They get populated on a crawl. User profile crawls have never been reliable.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for you response.
Can you please suggest how else can i confirm if there is data in the the RefinableDate17

Comment: Run the query and return RefinableDate17 as a property. I do know that the Birthday field is peculiar. IIRC it does not store year. Try using the Search Query Tool: https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/releases